# System is computationally singular using mlogit in R

Tags: r, mlogit

I am conducting multinomial logistic regressions. They seem to work for all variables except for the price variable, where I get the following error:

```
reg.M <- mlogit::mlogit(formula = value ~ 1 | price, data = listDatasets[[2]])

Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 7.4671e-18
```

That is my the head of the dataset used (I have 15 like these, with different prices):

```
> head(listDatasets[[2]])
             index Age ScoreEnvAtt MoneyInvested Gender Beliefs_eff_Green Beliefs_eff_ESG Beliefs_eff_Comp Beliefs_perf_ESG Beliefs_perf_Green Beliefs_perf_Comp Guilt Social.Altruistic Biospheric Egoistic DummyMedium
1.SS_Green_1     1  26         4.2            13      2                 4               3                3                2                  3                 2    71          6.000000   6.000000        5           1
1.SS_Green_2     1  26         4.2            13      2                 4               3                3                2                  3                 2    71          6.000000   6.000000        5           1
1.SS_Green_3     1  26         4.2            13      2                 4               3                3                2                  3                 2    71          6.000000   6.000000        5           1
1.SS_Green_4     1  26         4.2            13      2                 4               3                3                2                  3                 2    71          6.000000   6.000000        5           1
2.SS_Green_1     2  30         4.8             2      2                 4               3                4                2                  3                 3    26          6.666667   5.333333        5           1
2.SS_Green_2     2  30         4.8             2      2                 4               3                4                2                  3                 3    26          6.666667   5.333333        5           1
             DummyHigh CompensationGroup Past_compensation Knowledge_CO2   variable value price
1.SS_Green_1         0            Group1                 2             1 SS_Green_1 FALSE   1.5
1.SS_Green_2         0            Group1                 2             1 SS_Green_2 FALSE   1.5
1.SS_Green_3         0            Group1                 2             1 SS_Green_3 FALSE   1.5
1.SS_Green_4         0            Group1                 2             1 SS_Green_4  TRUE   1.3
2.SS_Green_1         0            Group2                 2             2 SS_Green_1 FALSE   1.5
2.SS_Green_2         0            Group2                 2             2 SS_Green_2 FALSE   1.5
```

I checked the other threads on this error already but can not find a solution to my problem. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit: I tried to do it with `multinom` instead of `mlogit`. It does not seem to recognize the levels of the dependent variable.

```
test <- multinom(value ~ price, listDatasets[[2]])
```

summary(test)

```
    > summary(test)
Call:
multinom(formula = value ~ price, data = listDatasets[[2]])

Coefficients:
               Values Std. Err.
(Intercept)  25.77925  1.464741
price       -18.86853  1.037180

Residual Deviance: 653.8391 
AIC: 657.8391
```

Edit 2:

```
dput(head(data_long))
structure(list(Pride = c(17, 71, 1, 50, 0, 13), Guilt = c(71, 
26, 89, 50, 100, 13), Shame = c(36, 77, 5, 50, 67, 8), Joy = c(12, 
50, 0, 50, 30, 37), Attitudes1 = c(6, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5), Attitudes2 = c(5, 
7, 3, 4, 5, 3), Attitudes3 = c(6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6), Attitudes4 = c(5, 
3, 5, 5, 6, 6), Attitudes5 = c(4, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6), Attitudes6 = c(5, 
7, 3, 7, 7, 6), Attitudes7 = c(3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 6), Attitudes8 = c(3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 2), Attitudes9 = c(2, 3, 7, 4, 7, 6), Attitudes10 = c(3, 
2, 5, 4, 7, 6), Concern1 = c(6, 4, 7, 6, 7, 6), Concern2 = c(6, 
6, 7, 6, 7, 6), Concern3 = c(5, 5, 7, 6, 4, 6), Concern4 = c(6, 
6, 5, 6, 4, 5), Concern5 = c(6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 5), Concern6 = c(6, 
6, 7, 6, 5, 6), Concern7 = c(6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6), Concern8 = c(4, 
4, 5, 6, 3, 6), Concern9 = c(6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7), Beliefs_perf_ESG = c(2, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 2), Beliefs_perf_Comp = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2), Beliefs_perf_Green = c(3, 
3, 3, NA, 3, 2), Beliefs_eff_ESG = c(3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3), Beliefs_eff_Comp = c(3, 
4, 2, 4, 2, 3), Beliefs_eff_Green = c(4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3), Eval_Ego = c(3, 
2, 3, 4, 2, 3), Eval_Nature1 = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2), Eval_Nature2 = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 2, 3), Eval_Social = c(3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3), Reforestation = c(2, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 3), Renewable_Energy = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1), Efficient_Energy = c(3, 
4, 4, 3, 3, 2), Methane = c(4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4), France = c(3, 
3, 1, 1, 3, 2), Europe = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3), Development = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1), Co_benefits = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4), Poverty = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1), Health = c(4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3), Biodiversity = c(2, 
4, 1, 3, 2, 2), Equality = c(3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), Economic_Growth = c(5, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4), Knowledge_CO2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2), Past_compensation = c(2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Age = c(26, 30, 30, 30, 21, 40), Gender = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), MoneyInvested = c(13, 2, 1, 3, 13, 1), Investment_Experience = c(2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1), Participant_s_ID = c("1234asdf", "Password04", 
"hiquet8350", "masmas2121", "1712flju", "Lemurien4555"), Compensationproject1 = c(1, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, 1), Compensationproject2 = c(NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
NA), Compensationproject3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment1 = c(6, 
14, 3, 13, 10, 7), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment2 = c(3, 1, 4, 6, 
13, 2), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment3 = c(7, 10, 1, 7, 11, 13), 
    FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment4 = c(11, 15, 5, 2, 4, 11), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment5 = c(14, 
    7, 2, 11, 2, 10), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment6 = c(2, 11, 8, 
    15, 5, 6), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment7 = c(1, 6, 6, 12, 14, 
    1), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment8 = c(10, 2, 14, 5, 9, 5), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment9 = c(4, 
    8, 13, 1, 1, 8), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment10 = c(12, 5, 7, 
    14, 6, 3), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment11 = c(15, 13, 10, 10, 
    12, 14), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment12 = c(13, 3, 12, 8, 7, 
    9), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment13 = c(9, 9, 11, 9, 8, 15), 
    FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment14 = c(8, 12, 9, 3, 3, 12), FL_42_DO_ChoiceExperiment15 = c(5, 
    4, 15, 4, 15, 4), ScoreEnvAtt = c(4.2, 4.8, 4.9, 5, 5.9, 
    5.2), Eval_NatureScore = c(3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 2, 2.5), Social.Altruistic = c(6, 
    6.66666666666667, 6, 6, 5, 5.66666666666667), Biospheric = c(6, 
    5.33333333333333, 7, 6, 7, 6), Egoistic = c(5, 5, 6.33333333333333, 
    6, 4, 6), GroupEnvAtt = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("low", "medium", "high"), class = "factor"), 
    DummyMedium = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), CompensationGroup = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"
    ), class = "factor"), ID = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
    "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
    "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", 
    "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
    "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", 
    "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", 
    "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", 
    "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", 
    "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", 
    "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
    "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
    "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
    "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
    "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
    "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", 
    "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", 
    "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
    "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", 
    "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", 
    "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", 
    "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", 
    "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", 
    "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", 
    "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", 
    "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "245", "246", 
    "247"), class = "factor"), ChoiceSet = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Baseline_Choice_1", "Baseline_Choice_2", 
    "Baseline_Choice_3", "Baseline_Choice_4", "SS_Green_1", "SS_Green_2", 
    "SS_Green_3", "SS_Green_4", "SS_Green_ESG_1", "SS_Green_ESG_2", 
    "SS_Green_ESG_3", "SS_Green_ESG_4", "SS_ESG_1", "SS_ESG_2", 
    "SS_ESG_3", "SS_ESG_4", "SS_Comp_Green_1", "SS_Comp_Green_2", 
    "SS_Comp_Green_3", "SS_Comp_Green_4", "SS_Comp_ESG_1", "SS_Comp_ESG_2", 
    "SS_Comp_ESG_3", "SS_Comp_ESG_4", "SS_Comp_1", "SS_Comp_2", 
    "SS_Comp_3", "SS_Comp_4", "SS_All_1", "SS_All_2", "SS_All_3", 
    "SS_All_4", "WTP_All_1", "WTP_All_2", "WTP_All_3", "WTP_All_4", 
    "WTP_Comp_1", "WTP_Comp_2", "WTP_Comp_3", "WTP_Comp_4", "WTP_Comp_ESG_1", 
    "WTP_Comp_ESG_2", "WTP_Comp_ESG_3", "WTP_Comp_ESG_4", "WTP_Comp_Green_1", 
    "WTP_Comp_Green_2", "WTP_Comp_Green_3", "WTP_Comp_Green_4", 
    "WTP_ESG_1", "WTP_ESG_2", "WTP_ESG_3", "WTP_ESG_4", "WTP_ESG_Green_1", 
    "WTP_ESG_Green_2", "WTP_ESG_Green_3", "WTP_ESG_Green_4", 
    "WTP_Green_1", "WTP_Green_2", "WTP_Green_3", "WTP_Green_4"
    ), class = "factor"), value = c("Off", "Off", "Off", "Off", 
    "Off", "Off"), Choice = c("Conventional", "Conventional", 
    "Conventional", "Conventional", "Conventional", "Conventional"
    ), price = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `price` not an attribute of the choices? The formula you have now models it as an attribute of the subjects, see the difference here from an example in the `mlogit` documentation:

```
## a pure "conditional" model
summary(mlogit(mode ~ price + catch, data = Fish)) #what you should have if price is an attribute of the choice options
## a pure "multinomial model"
summary(mlogit(mode ~ 0 | income, data = Fish)) #what you have now
```

So in your case `reg.M <- mlogit::mlogit(formula = value ~ price, data = listDatasets[[2]])`

What you did with `multinom` is what I mean (you fitted a conditional logit model, i.e., modeled price as an attribute of the choices). The model recognizes the levels of the dependent variable, but `price` in your model is modeled as a variable with a generic coefficient (one that is the same for all alternatives).

"...while working with multinomial logit models, one has to consider three kinds of variables :
•

- alternative specific variables xij with a generic coefficient β,
- individual specific variables zi with an alternative specific    coefficients γj ,
- alternative specific variables wij with an    alternative specific coefficient δj .

The satisfaction index for the alternative j is then :
Vij = αj + βxij + γjzi + δjwij" ([Source](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.303.7401&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

So if you want the third option from the list above, use this formula: `reg.M <- mlogit::mlogit(formula = value ~ 0 | 1 | price, data = listDatasets[[2]])`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, price is an attribute of the choices and it does not change within a choice set. That means, Choice 1 = 1.5, Choice 2 = 1.5, Choice 3 = 1.5, Choice 4 = 1.3. I have 15 of these choice sets and the prices vary between but not within. Can I even use the `price` variable as a predictor? 

I tried the price as alternative specific variable, also tried your code aboce but I get the same mistake as before.

Comment: I am thinking if I put all choice environments in one table (now one list is one choice-set) then it could work? Because every individual made 15 choices. The choices were always the same, but the price changed.

Comment: Yes I think you should use all the choice situations at once and set the `panel` argument to `TRUE`

Comment: I transformed the table and have now everything as a panel but now it won't run any regression anymore. I tried to add `panel` and `rpar`. Do you know how I would have to specify the regression now? I include the `dput(head)` of my data above.

Comment: `reg1 <- mlogit::mlogit(formula = Choice ~ price | ScoreEnvAtt, data = data_long, panel = TRUE, rpar= c(ScoreEnvAtt = "n", price = "n"))` I tried this for example

Comment: Did you convert your data to the format `mlogit` wants first? With `mlogit.data` or `dfidx` in the newest package version. Please post a new question if it still doesn't work. Your question was about why you get the singularity error which I think I answered. Happy to provide more help but it is too cumbersome like this.